# Environment variable undefined on the client side - NextJS + docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, environment-variables

My app is running on a VPS, with Docker Compose. I have a .env file in the file's directory, at the same level as the docker-compose.yml.

In my docker-compose, I set the environment variables like this:

[image: screenshot of the docker-compose.yml]

Everything is working fine when I run the app locally, but the problem is for the deployed app:

I can access the variables only on the Server side, in the getServerSideProps function. However, I get undefined on the client side (I am trying to access the ones starting by NEXT_PUBLIC_).

My workaround was to pass the value of the env variable I need from getServerSideProps to my page as a props, but it is very unconvenient and certainly not the right solution.

Do you know what can cause this issue?

Also, on the VPS, when I inspect the container of the NextJS app (docker exec -it ...), I type "env" and I see that the environment variables are there so I don't understand why they are not received on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Just going off of the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) it says:

> The value will be inlined into JavaScript sent to the browser because of the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix. **This inlining occurs at build time**, so your various NEXT_PUBLIC_ envs need to be set when the project is built.

The environment variables you are setting in the docker compose are **not** available at build time, only at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. Stupid question but how can I set them at build time?
With a .env file located at the NextJS directory root?
If so, should I add it to the .dockerignore file?

Comment: The .env file would work. You don't necessarily need to add it to the .dockerignore, but you can if you want.

Comment: I created a .env but still got undefined on the client side when i console.log the variables

Comment: Make sure you have set up ENV before `RUN npm run build` in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

as document says, if your env var has prefix "NEXT_PUBLIC_" it can be visible on client side, but if this is not the case for example after building without docker and testing build files with "npm start" the problem exist , might be because of wrong environment used by command, if not it must be problem with docker side!
by the way you can use env-cmd library also